# Parsing street addresses in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, parsing

I am processing addresses into their respective field format for the database. I can get the house number out and the street type but trying to determine best method to get the street without number and last word. A standard street address received would be:

```
    res[:address] = '7707 Foo Bar Blvd'
```

As of now I can parse the following:

```
    house = res[:address].gsub(/\D/, '')
    street_type = res[:address].split(/\s+/).last
```

My first challenge is how to get 'Foo Bar'.  Note the street name could be one, two or three words.  I am struggling to find a one line expression solution for this in Ruby.

My second question is how to perhaps improve on the 'house' code to deal with house numbers that have an alpha at the end.  For example, "7707B".

Lastly if you can reference a good cheat sheet with examples for these expression that would be helpful.

Comment: Simple, don't do that!  either ask for the fields individually or store them as a whole.  parsing this will never be 100% accurate because the amount of variation is greater than you can figure out.  If you want a house number field (which you should not) have a house_number field in the form.

Comment: BTW:  There is an API with USPS.  https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm  they can verify your address and possibly give you better detailed info back.

Comment: The base property database that I am amending to has the fields separated in this way which is why the field house and street type.  I also have a full street address.  I am doing this for consistency in the data where possible

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend using a library for this if possible, since address parsing can be difficult. Check out the [Indirizzo](https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo) Ruby gem, which makes this easy:

```
require 'Indirizzo'
address = Indirizzo::Address.new("7707 Foo Bar Blvd")
address.number
 => "7707"
address.street
 => ["foo bar blvd", "foo bar boulevard"]
```

Even if you *don't* use the Indirizzo library itself, reading through its source code is probably very useful to see how they solved the problem. For instance, it has finely-tuned regular expressions to match different parts of an address:

```
Match = {
  # FIXME: shouldn't have to anchor :number and :zip at start/end
  :number   => /^(\d+\W|[a-z]+)?(\d+)([a-z]?)\b/io,
  :street   => /(?:\b(?:\d+\w*|[a-z'-]+)\s*)+/io,
  :city     => /(?:\b[a-z][a-z'-]+\s*)+/io,
  :state    => State.regexp,
  :zip      => /\b(\d{5})(?:-(\d{4}))?\b/o,
  :at       => /\s(at|@|and|&)\s/io,
  :po_box => /\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\b/
}
```

These files from its source code can give more specifics:

- https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/blob/master/lib/indirizzo/address.rb
- https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/blob/master/lib/indirizzo/constants.rb
- https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/blob/master/lib/indirizzo/numbers.rb

(But I would also generally agree with @drhenner's comment that, in order to make this easier on yourself, you could probably just accept these data inputs in separate fields.)

**Edit:** To give a more specific answer about how to remove the street suffix (e.g., "Blvd"), you could use Indirizzo's regular expression constants (such as `Suffix_Type` from `constants.rb`) like so:

```
address = Indirizzo::Address.new("7707 Foo Bar Blvd", :expand_streets => false)
address.street.map {|street| street.gsub(Indirizzo::Suffix_Type.regexp, '').strip }
 => ["foo bar"]
```

(Notice I also passed `:expand_streets => false` to the initializer, to avoid having both "Blvd" and "Boulevard" alternatives expanded, since we're discarding the suffix anyway.)

Comment: Stuart I looked at this gem but I did not see where it dealt with getting the street address without the street type.  Again just dealing with trying to match the data fields. I have a full street address as well just to make things easier to pull

Comment: Indirizzo doesn't appear to have a built-in method for separating the street _name_ from its suffix (e.g. "Blvd"). But it does have those suffixes as constants (such as `Indirizzo::Suffix_Type` from `constants.rb`. You could use these to parse out the suffixes. I've updated my answer with a suggestion on how to do that.

Comment: Stuart I will give that I try but it will take a bit of time to check out the Gem beyond what I did previously.  Looks like this might work and perhaps I will just switch out my previous code.  Will make correct once tested. Up for now.  Thanks

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have any other problems/questions and if it ends up working for you consider marking the question as accepted, thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can play fast and loose with named capture groups in a regex

```
matches = res[:address].match(/^(?<number>\S*)\s+(?<name>.*)\s+(?<type>.*)$/)
number = matches[:number]
house = matches[:name]
street_type = matches[:type]
```

or if you wanted your regex to be a little more accurate with the type you could replace 
    `(?<type>.*)`
with 
    `(?<type>(Blvd|Ave|Rd|St))`
and add all the different options you'd want

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use something like:

`^\S+ (.+?) \S+$`

`\S` matches any non white space character

`^` matches the beginning of the string

`$` matches the end of the string

And `(.+?)` captures anything in between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check your dataset to make sure if this problem hasn't already been handled for you.

I spent a fair amount of time first creating a taxonomy of probably street name ending, using regexp conditionals to try to pluck out the street number from the full address strings and everything and it turned out that the attributes table for my shapefiles had **already** segmented out these components.

Before you go forward with the process of parsing address strings, which is always a bit of a chore due to the inevitably strange variations (some parcel addresses are for landlocked parcels and have weird addresses, etc), make sure your dataset hasn't already done this for you!!!

---

but if you don't, run through the address strings, `address.split(" ")` creates an array of 'words'. In most cases the first "word" is the street number. That worked for about 95% of my addresses. (NOTE: my :address strings did not contain city, county, state, zip, they were only the local addresses)

I ran through the entire population of addresses and plucked the last "word" from each address & examined this array & plucked out any "words" that were not "Lane", "Road", "Rd" or whatever. From this list of address endings I created this huge matching regexp object

```
streetnm_endings = street_endings.map {|s| /#{s}/ }
endings_matches = Regexp.union(street_endings)
```

I ran through each address string, `shift`-ing out the first array member because, again that was the almost always the street number. And then gsub'd out the street endings to get what should be the street name sans street number or street name endings, which databases do not like generally:

```
parcels.each do |p|
  remainder = p.address.split(" ")
  p.streetnum = remainder.shift
  p.streetname = remainder.join(" ").gsub(endings_matches, "")
  p.save
end
```

It didn't always work but it worked most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I currently just pass whatever I am given to googlemaps and have them send back a formatted street address that is very easy to parse.

```
function addressReview(addressInput) {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressInput}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
    var addr = results[0].formatted_address;
    var latTi = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lonGi = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    $.post('/welcome/gcode',{ add: addr , la: latTi , lo: lonGi });
    $('#cust_addy').val(addr);
  } else {
    $('#cust_addy').attr("placeholder",'Cannnot determine location');
  }
} else {
  $('#cust_addy').attr("placeholder",'Cannnot determine location');
}
});
}
```

After that, I just split it up in ruby. with .split(', ') and .split(' ')