# Ruby Regex, splice up an Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to pull an address from a text file i am using regex to do it. the text file has hundreds of lines. i would like to pull the line that begins with address and ends with a \d{4}(the postal code.).

So $1 would be number $2 would be street name $3 would be suburb $4 would be city $5 would be postalcode.

```
...
Registration Number: 1996/001234/01
Address: 12 Long Street, Comer Maude and West, Sandton, 2196
Level Two Contributor
...
```

I have been looking at a few SO questions [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134877/parsing-street-addresses-in-ruby) gave me a cool gem once i have the address, but he had it already within a single line of string.

I wrote this regex within [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

```
/^Address: (\d+)\s(\w+\s\w+).(\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+).(\s\w+).\s(\d{4})$/
```

But its very specific for this one address, my regex foo sucks big time. I am thinking if there is a way to do number and words till the comma then to the next comma and then eventually end with the 4 digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addresses are not structured data, so you are going to struggle to generate a regular expression that will successfully handle them.

```
Address: 14 Wallaby lane, West Quay, 2014
Address: 14 Wallaby lane, West Quay 13, Extension 2, 2014
Address: 14 Wallaby lane, West Quay 13, Mazinga Junction, Extension 2, 2014
```

are all valid addresses.

You are going to have more success with something like this:

```
/^Address: (.*)(\d{4})$/
```

From which you will have to split on commas in $1 to match individual fields.

Comment: i ran the parser and your right its pretty hard to determine if it meets all the criteria. this solution is great because we can determine a lot just from the postal code.

Answer (score 1):

```
^Address:\s*([\w\d\s]+),\s*([\w\d\s]+),\s*([\w\d\s]+),\s*(\d+)
```

You can try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/9

Comment: Wow thanks +1 for the regex site! that is really awesome thanks again